# Syntek Web Cam is not found

Tags: webcam, skype

here is the output from lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174f:6a33 Syntek Web Cam - Asus F3SA, F9J, F9Ss
```

it seems to be installed but Cheese software still doesn't find it on start up (Skype does the same :)

Do I need to switch the camera on somehow?

Answer (score 1):

try this is in French but very understandable on all commands

http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/syntek

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question but I used to have the same issue.
First , please issue the following command to unload the module :

sudo rmmod uvcvideo

Then , reload it by issuing the below command :

sudo modprobe uvcvideo quirks=16

You must do that every time you restart the laptop.